# Multiple Selenium instances on same machine?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

What is the best way to run multiple selenium instances in parallel if the tests are for:

1. same browser type
2. same machine

I've read this: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ScalingWebDriver and seems there is a systemic problem regarding running multiple Selenium instances on the same machine. But I'd like to ask the community if there is a way that I'm not seeing.

I have a working selenium instance run e2e tests. However, I would now like to run 5 of those selenium instances in parallel using the same browser type.

I've looked into Selenium Grid 2 and I'm not sure if it fits my use case. It seems like the main point of Selenium Grid 2 is to be able to distribute test according to browser version / operating system. But in my case, each test is for the same type, same browser version.

Running the standalone test works great!

## Running multiple Firefox processes:

But as I try to scale by spawning multiple Firefox processes, I get errors that mostly involve HTTP and `requests` error, including `BadClient` and `StatusError` and `Exception: Request cannot be sent`:

`webdriver.Firefox()`

## Using Grid

I've dug into the `webdriver.Firefox()` code and it looks like under the scenes, it's connecting locally:

`class WebDriver(RemoteWebDriver):
    def __init__(self, firefox_profile=None, firefox_binary=None, timeout=30, capabilities=None, proxy=None):
         ...
         RemoteWebDriver.__init__(self,
             command_executor=ExtensionConnection("127.0.0.1", self.profile, self.binary, timeout))`

The RemoteWebDriver instance seems to just connect to localhost on a free port that it finds. Which seems like the same command used by Grid when registering a node:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register`

Does Grid have any relevance for running parallel Selenium instances on the *same* machine? Or is it primarily a load balancer for instances running on various different machines?

Is it possible to have reliable, non-flaky instances of Selenium run in parallel on the ​*same*​ machine?  I get HTTP flakiness when I run them in parallel (lots of request cannot be sent or Bad Status Error or the browser closing before info can be read from socket)

What's the point of Selenium Grid 2?  Does it just act as a load balancer for parallel test runs on multiple machines?  If I ran grid locally with the hub and node on the same machine (all for FF), would it effectively be the same as me running multiple `webdriver.Firefox()` processes?

Or is there some more magic behind the scenes?